# New window installation

Tags: windows

I am replacing a window with a new window, not a replacement window, and the dimensions seem odd based on what I see available at stores. The dimensions are 26 3/4 inches wide, 51 1/2 inches high. I live in a 1950 Cape and wouldn’t expect the windows to be an uncommon size- is it?

Comment: I don't know about where you live, but where I live there's absolutely no such thing as a 'standard window size'. Windows are made to measure.

Comment: Good windows can be ordered to measure. Adequate home-center windows come in standard sizes and you are expected to frame and/or shim to fit them.

Comment: It might not be a common size you buy off the shelf.  Are you just buying the glass or a whole new window frame?